# I tried to import a 3GB system log file through elk but getting errors

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, syslog, elk

files started importing like this..through logstash..kindly suggest me how to remove the errors i use kv filter only in my conf program

```html
{
"authserver" => "a_India RADIUS",
"proto" => "6",
"devname" => "FW_1",
"10:56:12\tdate" => "2020-06-22\tlocal7\tnotice\t\ttime=10:56:11",
"host" => "kali",
"dstintf" => "wan1",
"path" => "/root/Cybrotech-/log00",
"subtype" => "webfilter",
"srcintf" => "ssl.root",
"method" => "domain",
"eventtype" => "ftgd_allow",
"hostname" => "webmail.accessarellc.net",
"cat" => "33",
"srcintfrole" => "undefined",
"dstip" => "20.73.98.154",
"type" => "utm",
"sessionid" => "677535",
"dstintfrole" => "wan",
"srcport" => "6095",
"url" => "/",
"profile" => "monitor-all",
"srcip" => "10.212.134.190",
"logid" => "07013312",
"policyid" => "17",
"eventtime" => "12803571",
"direction" => "outgoing",
"level" => "notice",
"@version" => "1",
"reqtype" => "direct",
"catdesc" => ""Health",
"action" => "passthrough",
"vd" => "root",
"dstport" => "443",
"service" => "HTTPS",
"@timestamp" => 2020-07-13T09:10:47.811Z,
"sentbyte" => "192",
"devid" => "FG0TK19907000",
"group" => "SSLVPN_Group",
"msg" => "URL belongs to an allowed category in policy",
"user" => "\ASINGH",
"rcvdbyte" => "0"
}
```

after some time i got this error on screen..

```html
"_type"=>"doc", "_id"=>"LzhxR3MBoH6QvDEw21Sy", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"Limit of total fields [1000] in index [log00_210270] has been exceeded"}}}}
```

Comment: Read all the lines of the system log file with doing some filters that we do in Kibana .

Comment: I need answer on Urgent basis if anybody knows ...Please answer

Comment: if anyone can help in this matter..kindly reply @HighPerformanceMark